# Explanation for EXPLAIN SELECT result

Tags: mysql

Normally I check my sql-statemens by

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ...
```

today I've tried the trial version "Jet Profiler for mysql" and it shows me the following explanation for this query

```
SELECT   c.categories_id,
         cd.categories_name
FROM     categories c
JOIN     categories_description_de cd ON c.categories_id = cd.categories_id
WHERE    c.parent_id = 0
AND      c.categories_status = 1
AND      c.group_permission_1 = 1 
ORDER BY c.sort_order,
         cd.categories_name
```

Unfortunately I can't figure it out.

This is the EXPLAIN result from command line. I couldn't paste the code because it was too long.
[image]

Comment: How about you just post the actual output of the `EXPLAIN` statement in your question?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: The grey boxes, interpretation of which the OP is asking for help, are not part of the `EXPLAIN` output...

Comment: @eggyal So the OP is having a problem with a piece of software?

Comment: @eggyal Sounds off-topic.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: Questions about "[*software tools commonly used by programmers*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" are on topic.

Comment: Yes, off-topic here; go to the vendor web site and watch the video.

Comment: This question belongs on [Jet Profiler's forum](http://www.jetprofiler.com/forum/categories/).

Comment: Sorry guys, I've edited my post. It's not a problem with the software it's a problem in understanding what the EXPLAIN statement mean.

Answer (score 1):

There's too much to explain all of the output of EXPLAIN here, and you weren't specific about what part of it you are having trouble understanding.

In addition to the link @dg99 shows to the MySQL manual, there are other resources available for understanding EXPLAIN. My company, Percona, has done many presentations in this area. We have a number of webinars online, which are free to view, but require registration.

- [Explain Demystified](http://www.percona.com/webinars/2012-02-22-explain-demystified) by Baron Schwartz, co-author of [High Performance MySQL, 3rd edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022343.do).
  Slides are available [here](http://www.percona.com/files/presentations/EXPLAIN_demystified.pdf).
- [MySQL Indexing: Best Practices](http://www.percona.com/webinars/2012-08-15-mysql-indexing-best-practices) by Peter Zaitsev, also a co-author of the HPM book.
- [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.percona.com/webinars/tools-and-techniques-index-design) presentation by myself (the title in that webinar may be different).
- [Really Large Queries: Advanced Optimization Techniques](http://www.percona.com/webinars/really-large-queries-advanced-optimization-techniques) by Peter Boros.

Briefly, here's what I see in your EXPLAIN output:

- The optimizer considers several indexes for `categories`, but I don't think any of them are the best for this query. Ideally, you'd use indexes to reduce the search to match only the rows you want to be in the result set.
- Secondarily, using an index to retrieve the rows in pre-sorted order so you don't have to bear that cost during every query. The sort-on-every-query is indicated by `using filesort`.
- The index used for `categories_description_de` is the primary key index. The only thing you could do better would be to put the description into the main `categories` table, and avoid the join.
- I would choose a compound index on `(parent_id, categories_status, group_permission_1, sort_order)`.
- I would recommend that you `ORDER BY c.sort_order` without also sorting by a second column from the other table. The second sort column causes the query to be `using temporary table`, which means it has to collect the full result before it can sort it. This is often a source of performance degradation.

PS: It would have been easier to see your EXPLAIN output if you had copy & pasted the text instead of a screenshot image. I had to download the image and view it offline so it would be readable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's everything you could ever want to know about EXPLAIN output: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html